# expand rows out based on two date columns

Tags: r

I have a dataset which looks like the following:

```
    gvkey                         conm datadate1 datadate2
1    6660 LEINER (P) NUTRITIONAL PRODS 31mar1982 31mar1991
2   61534           JACUZZI BRANDS INC 30sep1994 30sep2006
3    4071                  DRESHER INC 30jun1980 30jun1989
4  175010         CORK EXPLORATION INC 31dec2005 31dec2006
5  148363    WORLDWIDE FLIGHT SVCS INC 31dec1999 31dec2002
6  100276               KOBE STEEL LTD                    
7   11258                   WAJAX CORP 31dec1964 31dec2016
8   27668           MAVERIX METALS INC                    
9  103895               REMY COINTREAU                    
10 181653 DIREXION DAILY SP500 BEAR 3X
```

Where `datadate1` is a starting date and `datadate2` is an ending date. I would like to expand out the rows, such that:

```
1    6660 LEINER (P) NUTRITIONAL PRODS 31mar1982 31mar1991
```

Becomes:

```
1    6660 LEINER (P) NUTRITIONAL PRODS 1982   
2    6660 LEINER (P) NUTRITIONAL PRODS 1983 
3    6660 LEINER (P) NUTRITIONAL PRODS 1984   
4    6660 LEINER (P) NUTRITIONAL PRODS 1985
5    6660 LEINER (P) NUTRITIONAL PRODS 1986   
6    6660 LEINER (P) NUTRITIONAL PRODS 1987
7    6660 LEINER (P) NUTRITIONAL PRODS 1988   
8    6660 LEINER (P) NUTRITIONAL PRODS 1989
9    6660 LEINER (P) NUTRITIONAL PRODS 1990   
10   6660 LEINER (P) NUTRITIONAL PRODS 1991
```

Thanks in advance! If I am not clear let me know and I will edit the question.

Data:

```
structure(list(gvkey = c(6660L, 61534L, 4071L, 175010L, 148363L, 
100276L, 11258L, 27668L, 103895L, 181653L), conm = c("LEINER (P) NUTRITIONAL PRODS", 
"JACUZZI BRANDS INC", "DRESHER INC", "CORK EXPLORATION INC", 
"WORLDWIDE FLIGHT SVCS INC", "KOBE STEEL LTD", "WAJAX CORP", 
"MAVERIX METALS INC", "REMY COINTREAU", "DIREXION DAILY SP500 BEAR 3X"
), datadate1 = c("31mar1982", "30sep1994", "30jun1980", "31dec2005", 
"31dec1999", "", "31dec1964", "", "", ""), datadate2 = c("31mar1991", 
"30sep2006", "30jun1989", "31dec2006", "31dec2002", "", "31dec2016", 
"", "", "")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Get the last 4 characters for the year:

```
library(stringr)
x %>%
  mutate(date1 = str_sub(datadate1, -4),
         date2 = str_sub(datadate2, -4))
```

Attempt:

```
y <- x %>%
  mutate(date1 = str_sub(datadate1, -4),
         date2 = str_sub(datadate2, -4),
         date1 = as.numeric(date1),
         date2 = as.numeric(date2)) %>%
  drop_na(date1, date2) %>%
  group_by(gvkey, date1, date2) %>%
  mutate(years = list(seq.int(from = first(date1), to = last(date2))))

y$years
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `complete` from `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  gather(var, year, datadate1, datadate2) %>%
  mutate(year = str_extract(year, '\\d+$') %>% 
           as.numeric() %>%
           replace_na(0)) %>%
  select(gvkey, conm, year) %>%
  group_by(gvkey) %>%
  complete(gvkey, conm, year = full_seq(year, 1)) %>%
  arrange(gvkey, conm, year)
```

Another method using `extract` instead of `mutate` + `str_extract`. Here, I've also dropped `NA`'s instead of turning them to `0`:

```
df %>%
  gather(var, date, datadate1, datadate2) %>%
  extract(date, 'year', regex = '(\\d+$)', convert = TRUE) %>%
  drop_na(year) %>%
  select(gvkey, conm, year) %>%
  group_by(gvkey) %>%
  complete(gvkey, conm, year = full_seq(year, 1)) %>%
  arrange(gvkey, conm, year)
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 100 x 3
# Groups:   gvkey [10]
   gvkey conm         year
   <int> <chr>       <dbl>
 1  4071 DRESHER INC  1980
 2  4071 DRESHER INC  1981
 3  4071 DRESHER INC  1982
 4  4071 DRESHER INC  1983
 5  4071 DRESHER INC  1984
 6  4071 DRESHER INC  1985
 7  4071 DRESHER INC  1986
 8  4071 DRESHER INC  1987
 9  4071 DRESHER INC  1988
10  4071 DRESHER INC  1989
# ... with 90 more rows
```

Comment: oooh Thats great! I am going to give it a go on my data. I got as far as this `y <- x %>%
  mutate(date1 = str_sub(datadate1, -4),
         date2 = str_sub(datadate2, -4),
         date1 = as.numeric(date1),
         date2 = as.numeric(date2)) %>%
  drop_na(date1, date2) %>%
  group_by(gvkey, date1, date2) %>%
  mutate(years = list(seq.int(from = first(date1), to = last(date2))))

y$years`  - which did what I wanted but created lists of the years instead of expanding the data.

Comment: @user113156 Not sure what should be done to blank years. Here, I turned them to `0`